# Spoofing a duplicate MAC address on an interface not connecting to the network where the original MAC is

Tags: networking, mac-address, spoofing

I'm trying to run a PHP project on a test server.

The project uses an internal framework that has been modified so it will only run on the production server by checking the MAC address in `eth0`, and encoded with ioncube, (I have no access to the original source files, so I cannot modify the framework in any way, i only have the ioncube encoded files that were created about 10 years ago).

My server has 2 network interfaces (`eth0` and `eth1`):

- `eth0` has the spoofed MAC address, and has no network cable connected.
- `eth1` has an IP (X.X.X.29) on the same network than the production server (X.X.X.30).

if I connect the computer to the same network as the production server, will be there a MAC Address conflict even though the spoofed MAC address is `eth0` and not `eth1`?

As a precaution, I've always bringing down the `eth0` interface before connecting to the local network, in order to connect to the internet.

My test server has CEntOS 6.7, while production has CEntOS 6.6.

Comment: Can you not just contact the vendor and get a trial/test license allocated to this MAC?

Comment: Oh no, it's not a license, it is our own software that was encoded about 10 years ago, now the person who encoded has left and there are no copies of the original source around :/ I just got this project, and I'm trying to get it into versioning, so getting the original source code or allocation to other mac address is currently out of question.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Yah, that's frustrating. :(

Comment: Yeah, it's posing a challenge for my short experience, but I'll overcome it and learn a lot from it (with trusty SF and SO communities by my side, ha).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some conflict could happend even if you forget disable eth0 or keep some ip on it. Because arp reply could go to another network. See http://linux-ip.net/html/ether-arp.html

For clean solution, enable arp_filter to prevent this on both server.

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/arp_filter
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, after reading about arp in the link you provided, i got a doubt: 
Would  `ip link set arp off dev eth0` work in disabling arp just for eth0? `eth0` is not intended to be connected to any network in this server, but I still want to be able to keep ARP on for eth1.